How should I select the ohm values for pull-up and pull-down resistors in a device with a USB Type-C connector used solely for power
Good morning, everyone. I am exploring the transition of the receptacle from a micro USB connector to a USB Type-C. Initially, my plan included implementing both sink and source capacity. However, with the assistance of individuals on this platform, I've realized the complexity involved in developing the port role detection circuit of Type-C, particularly in converting it to the ID signal for the original MicroUSB interface. Consequently, I now seek to prioritize the simplicity of ensuring power capacity and embracing the reversible nature of the connector.
In my quest for suitable pull-up and pull-down resistors for this purpose, I came across a table in an image. While the device has an input of 5V and 2.5A, I understand that achieving a higher current capacity requires the use of smaller resistor values and a PD IC (Power Delivery Integrated Circuit). However, I am still uncertain whether the standard Type-C connector supports only 5V and 1A or 5V and 500mA, as conflicting information from different sources has left me puzzled.
Moreover, I'm intrigued to know whether employing two 5.1 kΩ pull-up resistors on both DC pins would enable it to function as a UFP (Upstream Facing Port) and at least achieve the standard power transfer rate.

Thank you in advance.
PS: Apologies for any grammatical or stylistic errors; I'm still learning English.

The question is what exactly? 5k1 pull-ups are not a valid value.

@Justme Thanks for responding and for your patience!  Sorry for the previous error. The question is, if I add two 56 kΩ resistors to both CC pins, should I be able to charge the device with the standard 500 mA, 1 amp capacity, and could I negotiate the orientation without needing a USB-C port IC? Wouldn't it matter if the input capacity of the device is 5V, 2.5 amps? Should it still charge at a lower speed

No, having 56kohm resistors in your device means you want to be a device with DFP that provides up to 900mA out. Then you cannot be a device with UFP that takes in power. And it does not matter if you use a port controller IC or implement it yourself with resistors and maybe a MCU.
